# How to get information of specific user who has logged in?

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, django-views

## appname/views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')  # Redirect to a success page
        else:
            # Handle authentication failure (e.g., show an error message)
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid credentials'})

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

I want to filter the users login and want to see the specific user login information.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What information do you want to filter and get? Where do you want to save this info?

Answer (score 1):

you can access their information through the `request.user` object. This object represents the currently logged-in user and provides access to their attributes and methods.
to get the username of the currently logged-in user, you can use `request.user.username`. Similarly, you can access other attributes such as `request.user.first_name`, `request.user.last_name`, `request.user.email`, etc.

Here's how you can use this in your code:

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    username = request.user.username
    # You can access other user fields as well, such as email
    email = request.user.email
    # ... any other fields you have defined in your user model

    # You can then use the retrieved information as needed
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'username': username, 'email': email})
```

In the above Code, the `user_profile` function is decorated with `@login_required` to ensure that only authenticated users can access the profile page. Inside the function, `request.user.username` is used to retrieve the username of the logged-in user, and `request.user.email` is used to retrieve the email. You can access any other fields you have defined in your user model in a similar manner.

Comment: if a user is creating its own todo list and logout, and again he login  then the todo list shown of its own .

Comment: This answer looks AI generated, please delete